# How to fix core error while trying to auto set cookies in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, axios

I'm trying to login and then auto save cookies in browser there is the backend side config

[image]

And There is the frontend side

[image]

, with these config I can't make a request cuz am facing this error
[image]

but if I removed
**withCredentials: true**

it will work but without setting the cookies in the browser !!!
any help or recommendation ?